# The additive group of rationals is not finitely generated

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation

The additive group Z of integers is generator by 1 but additive group of rational numbers is not why?

Comment: Try expressing some non integral number as a sum of $1$'s and $-1$'s.

Comment: How would you get from one rational number to the next using the number 1?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a finite number of rationals $q_1,\ldots,q_n \in \mathbb{Q}$, consider the group generated by these rationals. What can you say about the denominator of any number (when written in reduced form) in this group?